# Python - Convert stringified list back to list

Tags: python, string, list, stringify

I have a stringified list:

```
a = ['one', 'two']
a = str(a)
```

After which, a would be

> "['one', 'two']"

Is there a way to go from this string format back to a list like the original format?

Thanks

Comment: ast_literal_eval or `ast.literal_eval`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use eval :

```
a = eval("['one', 'two']")
```

Comment: Please read why `eval` should be avoided in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/1903116)

Comment: The correct way is to use ast: import ast;  x = ast.literal_eval(a)